# What should I write in my jQuery function to get the value from my inputfield (id=btnCloseDeal) and display it on another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When enter/writing a name in a inputfield  (id=btnCloseDeal), and after that I click my GoToPayBtn Im coming to a new page. On my new page I wanna get the value from my inputfield  (id=btnCloseDeal) and display it. What should I write in my jQuery function to get the value from my inputfield  (id=btnCloseDeal) and display it on another page?

```
 <input type="button" class="artikel" id="btnCloseDeal" value="Pay" onclick="check();";"/>

$("#btnCloseDeal ").click(function (){}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, the way you are thinking of implementing it is not optimal.

I would suggest using your field (#btnCloseDeal) as a query parameter and then fetching it with jQuery.

Here is a function that will get you a query-param in pure JS

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
if(results == null)
  return "";
else
  return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: What is getParameterByName? Does your function return and displays the input name?

Comment: It gives you the value you put into #btnCloseDeal if you set that as a query param on the redirect url

Comment: Ok, I dont realy understand, but could you show me some code example?

Comment: Let's say you passed on the value to the url's query parameter: 
`valueOfInput = getParameterByName('btnCloseDeal')`
Your url would be something like: http://example.com/somepath?btnCloseDeal=YOUR-VALUE

Comment: What is valueOfInput? Should I write valueOfInput or some other value name?, I dont understand ...

Comment: Can you please based on my code, write a code example showing how to do it(all code together)?

Comment: Something like:
`$("#btnCloseDeal ").click(function (e){window.location.href="THE-PAGE-YOU-WANT-TO-HAVE-THE-DATA" + "?value=" + $('#btnCloseDeal').val();});`
And then on the page where you want to retieve the data just use the function I provided above (getParameterByName)

Comment: Ok, something Its happening. I can not see anything from my inputfield but im coming back to my start page and I can see that my url now is index.html?value=undefined.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong then, because I've just tested that in jsfiddle and it is working. Anyway I don't see the use of this, because the value isn't changed in the code you provided.

Comment: I think Im doing something wrong somewhere ... What do you mean with value isn't changed in the code you provided?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the value of the input to the url of a page you want to redirect to, then get the url parameter with javascript on that page:

```
// get the url
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
```

and use:

```
var param = location.search;
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I click my other button Im coming to a new page, but the url is always index.html ... Everything displays on the same url.

Comment: you can use location.search to get parameter like index.html?param=value

Comment: Ok, I dont really understand. Can you show me some code example using my code?

Comment: get the value from input, set the parameter on url then go to another page: `$("#btnCloseDeal ").click(function (){ window.location = 'your page url'+'?val='+$('#btnCloseDeal').val() }` then on another page get the val with `location.search` and display it

Comment: I think I understand your function, but what is location.search? Should I write location.search?

Comment: location.search return ?val=value

Comment: Can you please give me a example with all code together based on my code?